# OpenERP function makes whole system slowing down

Tags: python, postgresql, plpgsql, odoo, openerp-7

With this particular function I am trying to process already uploaded raw attendance data into more informative way. Eg: late calculation, Regularize details etc. Also I am using this same function to update my attendance backup tables and making those attendance records against the calendar days by inserting those records to another table.

By executing this function whole ERP system getting slow (sometimes couldn't even login) and some random records are getting missed when this happens.

Please be kind enough and help me to solve this issue.

**The proc - *merge_db()***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_db()
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
 r record;
 recordCount integer;
 inTime varchar(10);
 outTime varchar(10);
 mintime varchar(10);
 maxtime varchar(10);

BEGIN

    FOR r IN (select distinct name , to_char(date,'yy/mm/dd') as date ,late_check from text_based_attendance where status = 0 and date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20 days') 
    LOOP

    select count(*) into recordCount 
    from  attendance_processed a 
    where a.name = r.name and a.reldate = r.date ;


    select  to_char(min(a.date), 'HH24:MI'), 
            to_char(max(a.date), 'HH24:MI') into mintime,maxtime
    from text_based_attendance a 
    where a.status = 0  and
    a.name = r.name and to_char(a.date,'yy/mm/dd')  = r.date;

    if recordCount > 0 then

        select  sign_in , sign_out into inTime, outTime
        from  attendance_processed a 
        where a.name = r.name and a.reldate = r.date; 


        if to_timestamp(inTime,'HH24:MI') > to_timestamp(mintime,'HH24:MI') then
            -- update signin
            update attendance_processed a set sign_in = mintime
            where a.name = r.name and a.reldate = r.date; 


        elsif to_timestamp(outTime,'HH24:MI') < to_timestamp(maxtime,'HH24:MI') then
            -- update signout
            update attendance_processed a set sign_out = maxtime
            where a.name = r.name and a.reldate = r.date; 

        end if;



    else
    --insert

        insert into attendance_processed
            (name,reldate,sign_in,sign_out,late_check)
        values (r.name,r.date,mintime,maxtime,r.late_check);                 
    end if;


    END LOOP;

--delete 62 days old records from text_based_attendance and backup it on text_based attancedance_backup table;
-- code written on python file hr_attendance.py


END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION merge_db()
  OWNER TO openerp;
```

**The function**

```
    def text_files_process(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        search_condition1 = [('status', '=', 0)]
        attendance_obj = self.pool.get('text.based.attendance')
        attendance_ids = attendance_obj.search(cr, uid, search_condition1, context=context)
        attendance_similar_objs = attendance_obj.browse(cr, uid, attendance_ids, context=context)

        if attendance_similar_objs:


            #Drop trigger if exists
            cr.execute("""
                    UPDATE attendance_processed set cnt_update='',cnt_insert=''

            """)

            cr.execute("""
                    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS attendace_holidays_leave_update ON hr_holidays

            """)

            cr.execute("""
                    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS attendace_holidays_leave_insert ON hr_holidays

            """)

            cr.execute("""
                    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS attendace_holidays_update ON attendance_processed

            """)

            cr.execute("""
                    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS attendace_holidays_insert ON attendance_processed

            """)

            #Run the procediur
            cr.callproc('merge_db')             

            for obj in  attendance_similar_objs:
               obj.write({'status': 1})



            cr.execute(""" delete from attendance_processed where name is null """)
            cr.execute(""" delete from attendance_logtrail where date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 days """)
            # to insert 65 days old data to text_based_attendace_backup table
            cr.execute(""" insert into
                        text_based_attendance_backup(name,date,in_out,status,create_uid,create_date,write_uid,write_date,unique_record,
                        location_code,machine_code,deleted_date)
                        (select name,date,in_out,status,create_uid,create_date,write_uid,write_date,unique_record,
                        location_code,machine_code,current_date 
                        from text_based_attendance t 
                        where t.date <
                        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '65 days') """)

            #to remove 65 days old data from text_based_attendace table
            cr.execute(""" delete from text_based_attendance t 
                        where t.date <
                        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '65 days' """)


            #to convert char to date field
            cr.execute("""
                          update attendance_processed a set date_calendar = to_date(a.reldate, 'YY-MM-DD') 
                          where to_date(a.reldate,'YY-MM-DD') > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '60 days' 
                          and a.date_calendar is null

                        """)
#new modification

            cr.execute(""" 
                        update attendance_processed a set employee_id = hr_employee.employee_no, employe_name = hr_employee.id
                        from hr_employee
                        where hr_employee.card_no = a.name and a.employee_id is null and hr_employee.current_status = 'active'

                        """)


            #to update the late time
            cr.execute(""" 
                    update attendance_processed set 
                    late_time_1 = (case when (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (sign_in)::time)  -  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '08:30')) / 3600.0 > 0.05 
                    then  0.05 else (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (sign_in)::time) -  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '08:30')) / 3600.0  end),
                    late_time_2 = (case when (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (sign_in)::time)  -  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '08:30')) / 3600.0 < 0.06666
                    then  0.0 else
                    case when (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (sign_in)::time)  -  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '08:33')) / 3600.0 > 0.2 
                    then  0.2 else (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (sign_in)::time) -  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '08:33')) / 3600.0  end end),
                    late_time_3 = (case when (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (sign_in)::time) -  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '08:45')) / 3600.0 > 0.0 
                    then  (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (sign_in)::time) -  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '08:45')) / 3600.0 else 0.0   end)
                    where   to_timestamp(reldate||' '||sign_in,'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI')  >  to_timestamp(reldate||' 08:30','YY/MM/DD HH24:MI') 
                    and to_timestamp(reldate||' '||sign_in,'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI')  <  to_timestamp(reldate||' 10:30','YY/MM/DD HH24:MI') and to_date(reldate, 'YY-MM-DD') >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20 days'
                    """)
#and to_date(reldate, 'YY-MM-DD') >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20 days' and current_status = True             



            #To Flag Roster Attendance
            cr.execute(""" 
                        update attendance_processed b set is_roster = True 
                        where b.id IN (
                        select id from attendance_processed a where a.employee_id IN (
                        select h.employee_no from hr_employee h, employee_category_rel mc, hr_employee_category cc 
                        where h.id = mc.emp_id and cc.id = mc.category_id  
                        and cc.name = 'Roster' and h.current_status='active')
                        and to_date(a.reldate, 'YY-MM-DD') >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 days' )

                        and id NOT IN (select id from attendance_processed aa where
                    aa.is_roster = True) """)


            now = dt.datetime.now().date()
            days = dt.timedelta(days=-8)
            check = now + days
            attendance_object = self.pool.get('attendance.processed')
            search_condition2 = [('name', '!=', ''),('date_calendar','>', check )]
            attendance_obj_ids=attendance_object.search(cr, uid, search_condition2, context=context)
            attendance_objects=attendance_object.browse(cr, uid, attendance_obj_ids, context=context)
            fulldate = False
            if attendance_objects:
                for att_obj in attendance_objects:

                    if att_obj.reldate:
                        fulldate = datetime.strptime(att_obj.reldate, '%y/%m/%d')

                        search_condition3 = [('date', '=', fulldate)]
                        company_holiday_obj = self.pool.get('company.holidays')
                        search_ids=company_holiday_obj.search(cr, uid, search_condition3, context=context)
                        browse_ids=company_holiday_obj.browse(cr, uid, search_ids, context=context)


                        try: 
                            intime = datetime.strptime(att_obj.sign_in,'%H:%M')
                            outtime = datetime.strptime(att_obj.sign_out,'%H:%M')
                        except:
                            intime = datetime.strptime('11:11','%H:%M')
                            outtime = datetime.strptime('11:11','%H:%M')


                        bol = False   

                        if browse_ids:
                            day_type='holiday'
                        elif fulldate.isoweekday() in (6, 7):
                            day_type='weekend'
                        else:
                            #delta.seconds
                            day_type='normal'


                        if day_type =='normal':

                            delta = (outtime - intime)
            #                print delta
                            minutes = (delta.seconds)/60
                            if minutes <= 240:
                                bol = True
                                action = 'r'
                            else:
                                bol = False
                                action = 'n'



                        elif intime == outtime:
                            bol = True
                            action = 'r'

                        else:
                            bol = False
                            action = 'n'                        
                        # in here 'need_regulaized' for check time     
                        att_obj.write({'day_type': day_type,'action':action, 'need_regulaized':bol})

            #Update attendance_processed_days
            cr.execute(""" truncate attendance_processed_days """)


            cr.execute("""
                  INSERT INTO attendance_processed_days (id, sign_out2,leave_or_holiday,sign_in,date,
                  sign_out,employee_id,late_time_2,late_time_3 ,late_time_1,employe_no,sign_in2,dept_name,division_name,section_name,category,action) 

                  SELECT id, sign_out2,leave_or_holiday,sign_in,date,
                  sign_out,employee_id,late_time_2,late_time_3 ,late_time_1,employee_no,sign_in2,dept_name,division_name,section_name,category,action 
                  from employee_attendance_with_holidays where employee_no is not null

                 """)

            #to update missing company
            cr.execute(""" 
                    update attendance_processed_days a set comp_id = c.company_id from hr_dept_n_registration c
                        where a.dept_name = c.id
            """)



            #to update missing dept/div/sec/com
            cr.execute("""
                    UPDATE
                      attendance_processed_days a 
                      SET
                      division_name = aa.division_name,
                      dept_name = aa.dept_name,
                      section_name = aa.section_name,
                      comp_id = aa.comp_id
                      From (select distinct employe_no, division_name,dept_name,section_name,comp_id 
                      from attendance_processed_days where comp_id is not null) aa
                      WHERE 
                      a.employe_no = aa.employe_no
                      and a.comp_id is null
                      """)

            #to update late time
            cr.execute("""
                    update attendance_processed_days 
                    set late_time_1 = null , late_time_2 = null, late_time_3 = null
                    where (leave_or_holiday like '%Leave%' 
                    or leave_or_holiday like '%Half Day%')
                    and late_time_1 > 0
                        """)



            return False
```

Comment: try to run VACUUM ANALYZE after this function. It contains some deletes, some updates.

Comment: This is quite a large function and would be painful for us to actually find out why something is not work as intended. You need to help us out here. Start by refactoring this thing into easily understood pieces, then profile the function to see where exactly do we have delays. And once we know which part of the code is causing the delays then we can fix it.